# Flying to, but not entering, Turkey without passport

Tags: passports, turkey, isl, turkish-airlines, swedish-citizens

I am a Swedish citizen and will fly to Saudi Arabia (with approproate visa) shortly. My route is as follows;
Gothenburg-Istanbul and Istanbul-Riyadh (GOT-IST-RUH).
On the flight IST-RUH, I will be travelling with my mother flying from Stockholm (ARN-IST-RUH). We both fly with, and have booked our tickets at Turkish Airlines.

My question now is, can I travel to IST without my passport, meet with my mother in the international area of the terminal (provided that we end up in the same arrival terminal), receive my passport who my mother (who may pick it up from the visa application center) and give it to me for the continued travel.

In short; can I enter the terminal without passport, or do I need a passport already before entering the airport in Turkey?

Comment: Do you have documentation allowing you to enter Turkey? If not, the airline would be at risk of penalties and having to fly you back to Gothenburg if they let you board the first flight without all the documentation needed for the second flight.

Comment: I will have all documents once my mother and I can meet, including a passport allowing me to enter Turkey, and a visa valid for Saudi Arabia. Upon departure from GOT I would only have a Swedish drivers licence, usually fine for travel with some airlines within some European countries.

Comment: The airline in Gothenburg will have to depend on the documents you can show them at check-in, not on documents you might acquire after they have taken the risk of flying you to another country.

Comment: @Jonke-Pö Travel outside the Schengen Area usually requires a passport, and Turkey isn't in Schengen.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Usually? A passport or national ID card are required to exit the Schengen Area. Technically not when re-entering (although you certainly **should** have it or you will face delays), but you won't be able to exit without either of those

Comment: @Crazydre the question airline considering willnot be that whether or not you can exit or re-enter Schengen. They are hauling you to Turkey and/or Saudi, and in case you present yourself to Turkish or Saudi immigration for entry in the country, and they do not allow you in, not only airline has to immediately fly you back to anywhere you will be accepted, (on the spot tickets are very expensive), but also Saudi/Turkish authorities will heavily fine airline for bringing you to them.

Comment: @DavChana I understand that, but the point is that, even if, hypothetically speaking, the Airline would let OP board if he explained the situation, the fact remains that he Needs to clear Swedish immigration

Comment: @crazydre oh ok understood now.. although related, in Qatar if a resident has e-card, he just need that to exit the country, and fingerprints, although airline will not allow to board the outgoing flight without passport..

Comment: I have solved the issue in another way, but will try to find out the actual answer when I travel there. Thanks all

Comment: @Jonke-Pö Like I said, if nothing else, our dearest (not!) *gränspolis* won't let you get to the gate without a passport, period. Trevlig resa! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm Swedish too, and I tell you, you will **not** be able to board without a passport, **because** Turkey is outside of the Schengen Area

You can usually use your driving licence within Schengen (though not with Ryanair, Wizz or easyJet), because it counts as a single country, so flights from Göteborg to Greece (for example) are effectively domestic.

Turkey, however, is outside Schengen, meaning Sweden-Turkey flights count as *real* international flights. All over the world, this means going through passport control (also known as clearing immigration) at the departure (except in a few countries) and arrival airport, though not at transit airports if they have corridors for international connections (which IST does).

To clear immigration in Schengen countries, you need a passport or national ID card (issued by the police, though you probably don't have one of those). However, as you're going from Sweden directly to a country outside the EU and EFTA (Turkey), only a passport will do, due to the Swedish *passlag*.

So no, just no. Have your mother send you your passport by registered mail, or, if not possible, get a new passport ASAP - it takes 5 working days. In the latter case, ssk your mum to send you a high-quality photocopy of the passport's ID page to show at the police station together with your driving licence.

**Your Saudi visa in the old passport would still be valid together with your new passport.**

Comment: "...this means going through passport control...". I think that is the definite reason for why this is not possible.

Comment: @Jonke-Pö Exactly, even if Turkish Airlines **had** given you the OK, you **still** would not have reached your gate at Landvetter, because the border guards would have blocked you. Regardless of destination, you cannot pass those booths without either a passport or national ID card (a driving licence will not do) because of the rules for entering and exiting the Schengen Area. In other words, this is not just a mere airline issue

Answer (score 18):

You won't be able to board in GOT unless you have your passport; they'll check your documents for RUH at that point.  Maybe you can talk them into checking you in for the GOT-IST leg without issuing a boarding pass for the IST-RUH leg, but I wouldn't count on it if I were you, especially not on the strength of advice from strangers on the internet.

In fact, since Swedish citizens are not among those who can [enter Turkey with a national ID](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa), you will almost certainly be unable to board the first leg of your flight without your passport.

I would advise you to call the airline and run this idea past them.  They are the only ones who will be able to tell you whether they will allow you to board their airplanes.

Comment: Ok, then I will go retrieve my passport in advance. It was over three years ago I last time visited Turkey, so I didn't remember the process with TK nor how connecting flights work at IST.

Comment: I really don't see how that could work. The airline can't really "pretend" that Turkey is the final destination, since OP won't have the required document (passport) to enter Turkey, either.

Comment: @Jonke-Pö [IST works a lot like this.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76153/3221) But I have to agree that you aren't likely to be allowed to board your first flight without the passport.

Comment: @phoog Actually no, they don't, only citizens of [a handful of countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey#Visa-free) can. If you want an official source, consult Turkey's e-visa site, and see what it says for Swedish citizens with an ID card vs. with a passport.

Comment: @fkraiem so it is; I read my source too quickly.  I will revise my answer.  But Wikipedia is incorrect.  While Sweden is not among them, there are several countries missing from its list: http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa

Comment: @phoog I'm 99% convinced OP doesn't even have an ID Card - few of us do, to the point where many shopkeepers in Sweden and even some bureaux de change refuse to accept mine because they have **no** idea what it is (and I don't hold a Swedish DL). Driving licences are the default. Just like in the US, where few people other than border area residents have passport Cards

Comment: @phoog Also, although off-topic, speaking from experience, in practice the Turks generally won't refuse entry to a Swedish ID card holder (airlines letting you on is obviously a very different thing, since they go by official rules). I've entered several times by bus at the Kapikule and at Atatürk (during long transfers where my ID was sufficient for my destination), not even had my passport on me, and never been refused. I was slightly delayed at the Sarp checkpoint the one time I crossed there, but it worked out. Only works since I need no e-visa of course, or that system would block me

Comment: This answer was correct. The TK employee explained that due to their responsibility of checking that people that they transport to Turkey, they cannot allow me on the flight. If I would be stranded in the INTL arrival hall, they could be responsible for that. So technically there didn't seem to be any reason for being able to travel without a passport, but the airline would not take the risk of letting me be stranded on their account.

Comment: @Jonke-Pö Even if the Airline would have let you board, the border guards would not have let you reach your gate, regardless of whether the airline gave you a Boarding pass

Comment: @Crazydre do they check boarding passes? How would they know he's not flying somewhere that accepts the ID card, like the UK?

Comment: @phoog It's not about whether the *destination* accepts it, rather *Swedish law* defines ID cards as only being valid in the EU+Schengen. For example, there are direct flights from Sweden to Bosnia, Serbia, Montenegro, Kosovo and Macedonia, all of which accept my ID card. However, Swedish border guards would **not** let me board a direct flight to these. They see upcoming departures on the screen and can ask for the boarding pass if in doubt. In other words, if I want to go from Sweden to eg Serbia without my passport, I have to make a stopover in another EU or Schengen state

Comment: @phoog Also, like I said, OP probably doesn't have an ID Card (like I said, it's a small minority of Swedes that do) - he clearly said he sometimes uses his *driving licence* when flying - which is the default ID. The vast majority only have a DL and a passport - and Swedish border guards will **not** let you exit the Schengen Area on a DL, full stop. Hence my answer that it doesn't matter whether Turkish were to give leeway - OP would not have made it to his gate

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, **NO**.  Not a chance you should rely on.

Because GOT-IST is an international flight, the Turkish gate staff will verify all passengers have travel docs, almost always a Passport, during boarding.  They might not actually check it, just seeing that you have it.

Comment: @pnuts We answered at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

TK staff will not let you board the plane without a passport.  Suppose you succeeded in that. In IST the security checkpoint attendant will not let you take the escalators up to the transit hall. You will end up sitting in the airport police station for couple hours until your mom finds you and finally missing your connecting flight.

Comment: Does transit security at IST check travel documents? At SAW they don't, just the boarding pass