# Can I fly to (board) Turkey without passport?

Tags: france, turkey

I am a French citizen and I want to go Turkey. As I see in their Ministry of Foreign Affairs page, I can go to Turkey with my national ID. My passport is expired 3 years ago. And again, as I see in their Ministry of Foreign Affairs page, I can go to Turkey with an expired passport (5 years most) Looks like it's ok but when I am boarding the plane, will staff ask my passport? Or when I am going to gates, will the passport police ask my passport in the passport check point?

Comment: Where do you find this information that you can enter Turkey without a passport? I don't think this is the case. See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/flying-to-but-not-entering-turkey-without-passport

Comment: Here I found it. http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa

Comment: @lafemmecosmique This question is about a peculiar Swedish law and rules for Swedish citizens.

Comment: Interesting! In this case, perhaps your obstacle will be at the airport. If the airline understands that you can enter Turkey without a PP, it may be fine.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique I don't see how this is a duplicate. It seems very likely that the asker of the present question _does_ want to enter Turkey.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Exactly...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, ground handling staff will want to check your documents (because airlines can be held responsible if they bring someone without proper documentation) and you will have to go through an official passport control (Schengen exit check from the French police). But as a French citizen you can indeed enter Turkey with a national ID card and you won't even have to pay for the Turkish eVisa which many other European citizens have to get.

In practice, since the rules can be very complicated, airlines use a database called [Timatic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/ordinary-traveller-how-to-use-timatic) to figure out visa requirements and, as of today, it does include all the information you found on the official Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs website so I would not expect any trouble with the airport staff.

As for the police, there is no reason they should prevent you to leave but I don't really know. Leaving the Schengen area with a valid national ID card is definitely allowed and unproblematic. I don't think they should really be concerned about Turkey's rules but I suppose you might encounter a police officer who is surprised about it and requires an explanation. Nowadays, I mostly use the automated passport gates at major airports and nobody even asks for my destination so I have no first-hand experience to report. I don't know how the machines would respond to an expired document either.

Comment: So I can go out from Schengen exit check without my passport?

Comment: I will call the airline and ask. Maybe they know about the prosedure

Comment: @ÜnalBatuhanUysal Generally, yes, that's not a problem at all. I am regularly flying to the UK with my ID card for example. But last time I went to Turkey I did have a passport and used an automated gate so I don't know if the police cares about it. Holidays in Turkey are not uncommon so I think they should be familiar with it. The worse that could happen is to meet a police officer who doesn't know the rules but you can always explain them and point to the official website. It is definitely fully legal and not uncommon to go to Turkey and a few other countries without a passport.

Comment: They told me "Yes you can go"

Comment: Personally, I would never depend on another person or database being fully aware.  If I were in OP's place, I would carry a print-out of the official regulation.  And, if not flying on a Turkish airline, a French or English translation!

Comment: @WGroleau You always depend on them, I am not saying carrying a printout is not a good idea but it's still their decision and that situation isn't particularly complicated. Also, even flying on a Turkish airline, ground handling personnel is unlikely to speak Turkish.

Comment: @Relaxed "As for the police, there is no reason they should preven you to leave" They shouldn't, but sometimes do, at least those in ZRH, which isnt really legal AFAIK. To me who speaks German it's not an issue (I just confidently state my ID's enough for the destination), but my mum was almost refused exit from Switzerland until I could intervene on the phone.

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, I know, that's why I didn't phrase it more affirmatively.

Comment: @Relaxed So I talked with the airline , they told me that It's ok. I talked with a French citizen who entered Turkey with his ID many times. He told me I should fill out a paper which called "Entry and Exit Form to/from Turkey For Persons Travelling With An Id Card According to the European Agreement on Regulations Governing the Movements of Persons Between Member States of The Council of Europe"

Comment: @ÜnalBatuhanUysal You don't fill it out yourself - the officer does (usually only your name, although there are more fields). When exiting, present the ID Card AND the form, because it'll get stamped again

Comment: @ÜnalBatuhanUysal with a title like that, there may be no more room on the form to enter any information!

Comment: @phoog Actually that's only what it's called at the land borders from Greece and Bulgaria. At the Istanbul Airports, it's "Entrance and Exit form on the border for persons who travel with indentification Card" (yes, it's spelt "indentification" xD). There are several different designs depending on where you enter

Comment: @ÜnalBatuhanUysal This is what the form Looks like at the Istanbul Airports (the White one) http://cokokuyancokgezen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/kibris-cikis-formu-640x853.jpg

Comment: @Crazydre Also I couldn't get why plural form of word "person" is persons but not "people" ...

Comment: @ÜnalBatuhanUysal Haha, yeah! Anyway you'll be fine. I'm Swedish and officially require a passport to enter Turkey, but in practice I've always been let in on my ID. Since French IDs are officially accepted, it's even better. The officer often won't fill out the entire form, which won't be a problem later on in my experience. However, carry that form **and** your ID at all times, as police checks have become very common especially in the Istanbul Metro

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks for your help, I really appreciate. I'll edit here 19/08/17